# Unable to sudo apt-get dist-upgrade due to Connection failed in 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I am executing dist-upgrade on ubuntu 16.04 and getting:

```
nisarg@nisarg-OptiPlex-790:~/$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      checkbox-ng gstreamer1.0-clutter libasm3-java libbind9-90 libcamel-1.2-52 libclamav6 libcolamd2.8.0 libdns100 libebook-contacts-1.2-1 libecal-1.2-18
      libedata-cal-1.2-27 libedataserver-1.2-20 libglew1.10 libglewmx1.10 libgps21 libgtop2-10 libimobiledevice4 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libisl13
      libjackrabbit-java libjna-java libjna-jni libjna-platform-java libjs-prototype libjs-scriptaculous libjsch-agent-proxy-java libkf5activities5
      libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libllvm3.5v5 liblouis2 liblwres90 libmaven-scm-java libmono-web4.0-cil libpoppler52 libpth20 libqpdf13v5
      libqt5extserialport1 libquazip-qt5-1 libraw10 libsisu-guice-java libusbmuxd2 libwlocate0 libx264-146 libx265-59 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-damage0
      plasma-framework python-characteristic python3-cffi python3-checkbox-ng python3-ply python3-pycparser qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols
      qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-org-kde-people qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-localstorage
      qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin telepathy-indicator unity-scope-audacious unity-scope-clementine
      unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-musique
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    The following packages will be REMOVED
      checkbox-ng-service gnome-control-center-shared-data libcdr-0.1-1v5 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libgnome-desktop-3-10 libhunspell-1.3-0v5
      libmarblewidget-qt5-22 libmetacity-private3 libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmwaw-0.3-3v5 libodfgen-0.1-1v5 libplank0 libpresage1 libpython3.4
      libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libvoikko1v5 openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless python3.4 python3.4-minimal tzdata-java
      unity-scope-musicstores xserver-xorg-input-mouse
    The following NEW packages will be installed
      a11y-profile-manager-indicator appstream autotools-dev ca-certificates-mono checkbox-converged default-jre-headless dh-strip-nondeterminism dirmngr
      distro-info-data efibootmgr fonts-lato fonts-noto-cjk fonts-symbola fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf
      fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf
      fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf fwupd fwupdate fwupdate-signed gcc-6-base
      gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-calendar gnome-software gnome-software-common gnupg2 gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 iio-sensor-proxy
      imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 imagemagick-common initramfs-tools-core ktexteditor-data ktexteditor-katepart liba11y-profile-manager-0.1-0
      liba11y-profile-manager-data libao-common libao4 libappstream-glib8 libappstream3 libbind9-140 libcamel-1.2-54 libcdr-0.1-1 libcglib-java libcheese-gtk25
      libcheese8 libclamav7 libcolamd2.9.1 libcommons-lang3-java libcommons-net-java libdata-alias-perl libdfu1 libdns-export162 libdns162
      libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-cal-1.2-28 libedataserver-1.2-21 libefivar0 libfftw3-double3 libfile-stripnondeterminism-perl
      libfilezilla0 libfwup0 libfwupd1 libgcab-1.0-0 libgeonames0 libgif7 libglew1.13 libglewmx1.13 libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgps22 libgtkspell3-3-0
      libgtop-2.0-10 libilmbase12 libimobiledevice6 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libisl15 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
      libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5gpgmepp5 libkf5service-bin libkf5texteditor5 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore libksba8 libllvm3.8 liblouis9
      liblouisutdml-bin liblouisutdml-data liblouisutdml6 liblqr-1-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblwres141 libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
      libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libmarblewidget-qt5-23 libmetacity-private3a libmono-accessibility4.0-cil libmono-ldap4.0-cil
      libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil libmono-system-design4.0-cil libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil
      libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil
      libmwaw-0.3-3 libnetpbm10 libnma-common libnma0 libnpth0 libodfgen-0.1-1 libopenexr22 libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader libplank1
      libplexus-component-annotations-java libplexus-component-metadata-java libplexus-container-default1.5-java libpoppler58 libpresage1v5 libprocps4
      libqdox2-java libqpdf17 libraw15 libreoffice-style-breeze libsnappy1v5 libsuitesparseconfig4.4.6 libusbmuxd4 libvoikko1 libvpx3 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
      libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libx264-148 libx265-79 libxapian-1.3-5 libxtables11 libyaml-libyaml-perl linux-base mesa-vdpau-drivers netpbm
      openjdk-8-jre-headless overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 pyotherside python-attr python-ptyprocess python3-guacamole python3-padme python3-ptyprocess python3-systemd
      python3-xapian1.3 qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside qmlscene qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-test-plugin ruby2.3 sbsigntool secureboot-db
      session-shortcuts snapd squashfs-tools ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-software ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial unity-accessibility-profiles
      unity-control-center-faces vdpau-driver-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      account-plugin-aim account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut account-plugin-yahoo alsa-utils apport apt-transport-https apt-xapian-index apturl
      apturl-common baloo-kf5 bamfdaemon base-files bash bash-completion bind9-host binutils bluez-obexd checkbox-gui checkbox-ng cheese cheese-common clamav
      clamav-base clamav-freshclam command-not-found command-not-found-data compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default
      compiz-plugins-extra compizconfig-settings-manager console-setup console-setup-linux cpp cpp-5 cups-browsed cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers
      debhelper dnsutils dolphin dolphin-plugins empathy empathy-common eog evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
      evolution-data-server-online-accounts fcitx-modules filezilla filezilla-common findutils folks-common fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-kinnari
      fonts-tlwg-laksaman fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typist
      fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-waree fuse g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 gcc-5-base gdb gdbserver gedit gedit-common gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
      gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0 gnome-contacts
      gnome-font-viewer gnome-menus gnome-screensaver gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
      gnome-system-monitor gnupg-agent google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
      gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gtk2-engines-murrine gvfs gvfs-backends
      gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs hplip hplip-data ifupdown indicator-appmenu indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard initramfs-tools
      initramfs-tools-bin initscripts iproute2 iptables isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-telepathy-approver
      kde-telepathy-contact-list kde-telepathy-desktop-applets kde-telepathy-text-ui kde-thumbnailer-deb keyboard-configuration kinit kio klibc-utils
      language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base libasan2 libastro1 libatomic1 libavcodec-ffmpeg56 libbamf3-2
      libboost-date-time1.58.0 libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-iostreams1.58.0 libboost-system1.58.0 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libcompizconfig0
      libdbus-glib2.0-cil libdbus2.0-cil libdecoration0 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedataserverui-1.2-1 libegl1-mesa
      libfolks-eds25 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libfuse2 libgail-3-0 libgcc-5-dev libgcc1 libgd3 libgdiplus libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-dri libglib2.0-cil
      libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls30 libgomp1 libgpgme11 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
      libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-cil libhpmud0 libhunspell-1.3-0 libitm1 libkf5baloo5
      libkf5balooengine5 libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5
      libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5parts-data libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5 libkf5peoplebackend5
      libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5 libkf5runner5 libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5textwidgets-data
      libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkf5webkit5 libklibc libktpcommoninternals9 libktplogger9 libktpwidgets9
      libkwalletbackend5-5 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblsan0 libmaven3-core-java libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.5-cil
      libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil
      libmono-sqlite4.0-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-data4.0-cil libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil
      libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
      libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil libmono-system-web4.0-cil
      libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmpx0 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2
      libnm0 libnotify0.4-cil libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common libpam-systemd libplank-common libplexus-containers1.5-java libpoppler-glib8 libpoppler-qt5-1
      libpresage-data libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-stdlib libqapt3 libqapt3-runtime libquadmath0
      libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome
      libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-galaxy
      libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core9 libsane-hpaio libsisu-guice-java libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6
      libsystemd0 libtotem0 libtsan0 libubsan0 libudev1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop
      libunity-settings-daemon1 libunity9 libupower-glib3 libvdpau1 libwagon2-java libwayland-egl1-mesa libwhoopsie0 libwnck-common libwnck22 libxatracker2
      libyelp0 light-themes lightdm lintian linux-firmware lp-solve lsb-base lsb-release lshw lvm2 marble marble-plugins maven mcp-account-manager-uoa
      metacity-common mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime mono-runtime-common mono-runtime-sgen nautilus nautilus-data network-manager network-manager-gnome
      network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome nodejs nodejs-dev nux-tools onboard plainbox-provider-checkbox plainbox-secure-policy plank
      plasma-framework poppler-utils ppp presage printer-driver-brlaser printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp procps python-apt python-compizconfig
      python-pexpect python-service-identity python-software-properties python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3 python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo
      python3-cffi python3-cffi-backend python3-checkbox-ng python3-commandnotfound python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-dbus python3-gdbm python3-gi
      python3-gi-cairo python3-louis python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-plainbox python3-pycurl
      python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-smbc python3-software-properties python3-uno qml-module-org-kde-telepathy qpdf
      rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins ruby seahorse shotwell
      shotwell-common software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk sonnet-plugins speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins
      suru-icon-theme systemd systemd-sysv totem totem-common totem-plugins ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola tzdata ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs
      ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-mono ubuntu-session ubuntu-wallpapers udev unity unity-control-center unity-lens-applications unity-lens-music unity-schemas
      unity-scopes-runner unity-services unity-settings-daemon update-notifier update-notifier-common upower usbmuxd whoopsie xorg xserver-xorg
      xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
      xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
      xserver-xorg-video-neomagic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128
      xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-savage xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
      xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware yelp zenity zenity-common
    472 to upgrade, 181 to newly install, 26 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
    Need to get 736 kB/529 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 412 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 bash amd64 4.3-14ubuntu1.1                                                                  
      Connection failed
    Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 bash-completion all 1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1.1
      Connection failed
    Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 bash-completion all 1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1.1
      Connection failed
    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bash/bash_4.3-14ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb Connection failed

    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bash-completion/bash-completion_2.1-4.2ubuntu1.1_all.deb Connection failed

    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

apt-get update works fine without any issues and I have also checked my proxy configuration - working fine.

I have tried --fix-missing option but that too does not solve the problem.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try to disable ipv6 by adding `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` when running `apt-get`.

If you want to make the setting persistent just create /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4 and put `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` in it:

`echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4`

Config options Acquire::ForceIPv4 and Acquire::ForceIPv6 were added to version 0.9.7.9~exp1 (see bug 611891) which is available since Ubuntu Saucy (released in October 2013) and Debian Jessie (released in April 2015).

Copied from the following post: [Convince apt-get *not* to use IPv6 method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method#100887)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/621919)

Comment: I edited the post to include the steps.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for updating your answer @torusJKL +1

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in my case after 15 of 30 packages to be updated the connection starts failing for all subsequent ones.
Also I found out that installing just one of the failing packages succeeds.

I fixed the problem by copying list of packages (which is listed in the beginning of `sudo apt-get upgrade` output).

Then I changed spaces/newlines into `\n\ssudo apt-get install -y\s` and saved result as file `update.sh` with execution permissions (`chmod +x update.sh`).

After running it with `sudo ./update.sh` all packages got upgraded properly.

Please note that this solution is far from ideal and is just a workaround.

Comment: To improve this solution you can manually make groups with eg 20 packages for each install command